# How do I properly use Bootstrap navbar for navigation?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

What I want to accomplish is to have the navbar always present and switch content on the rest of the page by pressing buttons on the navbar.

As a starting point I am using the basic example from the official bootstrap page:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

So to stick to this example I just want to have one content under the navbar when pressing the home button, another when pressing the about button, etc. ... 
Of course the buttons should be highlighted after pressing (like the home button atm).

To make this possible I have found one solution so far, which is:

- making a href to another html file when pressing the button
  `<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>`
- in the other html file is the same code for the header, instead of the other button being acitv
  `<li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>`

Although this solution is working i dont like it at all and this is why Iam asking here for a hopefully better way to do this.

Why I dont like my current solution:

- Its extremly redundant. When having many buttons in the navbar and I want to make a change to the navbar, I will have to change it in all of the copied versions for each button
- It needlessly loads html code. Shouldnt it be enough to load the navbar once and then change it dynamically on interaction?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are on the right path, but, unfortunately, this question is too broad for StackOverflow. I'd suggest to start from googling "Ruby on Rails" or "single page applications" and see what you can find out.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Ok I kind of hoped there is a functionality for that in bootstrap, but as it isnt I will shurely check out your suggestions.